# Boolean returning functions in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to return t or nil in Lisp just by calling the name of a function? The code below is self-explanatory but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I know there are other ways of achieving the same result but I am doing it to find out how boolean returning functions work in Lisp.

```
(print "Enter any number to check if it is greater than 5.")
(defvar v (read))
(if (check v) (print "It is greater than 5") (print "It is not greater than 5"))

(defun check(x)
    (if (> x 5) (t) (nil))
)
```

Comment: `(defun check (x) (> x 5))`?

Comment: Bad version: return T or NIL directly. Don't try to call them as functions. Better version: return the value of the `(> x 5)` form, since it already returns T or NIL.

Comment: It's better to read a basic intro book for Lisp, than guessing the language: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do

```
(if <condition> t nil)
```

because `<condition>` already returns the `t` or `nil` when testing.
So do

```
(defun check (x) <condition>)
```

In this case

```
(defun check (x) (> x 5))
```